# Getting specific filetype from URL Directory

Tags: c#, url, directory, file-type

Well, as title says, I want to get a specific filetype from a URL directory, something like `Directory.GetFiles("path", "*.jpg");` but from a url, here's an example:
`Directory.GetFiles("http:\\aurl.com\", "*.jpg");`
I want it for use it with `Image.FromFile(path);`. Any recommendation?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by *from a URL directory*?

Comment: Sorry for that, I mean something like `Directory.GetFiles("http:\\aurl.com\", "*.jpg");`

Comment: That is not possible. If you're talking about an Apache `Index of /` page or similar, you'd need to scrape it.

Answer (score 1):

Unless the web server is setup to give you an index of files when you hit "http://aurl.com", then it's not possible.

If you can get an index, then you'll have to parse the resulting HTML to get your list of JPG files.  The resulting HTML will differ depending on the web server.